# Unable to edit input element after an `alert` in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

### TLDR

I'm learning Electron. I have an HTML element `<input type="text">`, I can edit the text in it. After I do an `alert`, when i click the `input` element it shows no cursor, and pressing keys in the keyboard doesn’t change the text in the element. This doesn’t happen if I do the same in the browser, and I’m not sure if I’m doing something wrong.

### Minimum, reproducible example

#### Setup

In an empty folder in a terminal write:

```
npm init # And leave the defaults
npm install --save-dev electron
```

Then create `index.js`:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron");

app.on('ready', () => {
    let b = new BrowserWindow();
    b.loadFile("index.html");
});
```

And `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text">
    <button onclick="alert('foo');">Hi</button>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Steps to reproduce

1. On the terminal write `npx electron .` to start the application.
2. Edit the text in the `input`
3. Press the `Hi` button.
4. Close the dialog.
5. Click the `input` element.

The element doesn’t show a cursor, nor doesn’t it change to show that I’m editing it. Pressing keys in the keyboard doesn’t change the text in the `input`.

Clicking it multiple times selects the text, and it lets me delete it. But I’m unable to write new text.

[image: Actual behaviour]

##### Expected behaviour

Open `index.html` in the browser, and repeat the steps. In the browser the element shows a cursor, and I’m able to edit the text in it.

[image: Expected behaviour]

---

I’m not sure if I’m doing something wrong, or if this is actually the intended behaviour.

Here is the `package.json` if some information here helps:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^17.1.2"
    }
}
```

---

Something weird that I noticed while testing it after posting is that if I minimize the window, and open it again, I’m able to edit the input. It happens too if I open and close the developer tools.

Comment: On clicking the `Hi` button, an alert dialog appears and receives focus. You must clear the alert dialog (by pressing the alert dialog's `Ok` button) before you can re-focus you text field. If you are trying to create a system dialog, have you tried looking at Electron’s [dialog.showOpenDialog(…)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options) instead of using a HTML alert dialog?

Comment: @midnight-coding I edited the post to add the missing "Close the dialog" step, sorry. Me being unable to edit the `input` happens after closing it. Something werid that I noticed testing it after posting is that if I minimize the window, and open it again, im able to edit the `input`. It happens too if I open and close the developer tools.

Comment: Does this happen during development or only after packaging? If it is after packaging then perhaps the binaries are corrupt. You would need to delete your packaging path and re-package.

Comment: @midnight-coding Its happening during development. Ill try to package it to see if the problem is there too

Comment: This is a really weird problem. I reproduced your code on my system a while ago and everything seems to work correctly on my end. As a stretch, try deleting your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file. Then perform another `npm install` (just to make sure). It really looks like a Chrome issue and not an Electron issue. Electron does not get into the inner workings of Chrome to change behaviours like this.

Comment: @midnight-coding. Yep, seems like it was an issue with chromium. You might want to post an answer to get the bounty.

Comment: Did you checked it on some browser not only chromium based?

Comment: @Rooki [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest#what-is-electron) can only use Chromium as it is embedded within the framework and not swappable with any other browser(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is a really weird problem.

After reproducing the code on my system, everything appears to be working as per normal. IE: The alert box closes and one can still focus their cursor within the text box and even edit the text box without issue.

As Electron does not alter in any way the normal behaviour of Chrome and it works correctly on my (and other peoples) system, one can only come to a single conclusion. There is something wrong with Chrome.

To eliminate any possibility of Chrome file corruption, try deleting your `node_modules` folder and your `package-lock.json` file.

Following this, re-install Electron by running `npm install` at the command prompt.

Comment: Same issue for me, but this trick did not resolve it using electron v21  / Mac. What happens for me is single click is broke, but double click acts as single and the app looks unfocused. (title greyed out)

I noticed if I minimize the app, then open it again. then focus is restored and single click works. I suspect this actually is an electron issue. 

This behavior manifests about 50% of the time when I start the app. Its pretty random.

Comment: I replicated this myself and it doesn't seem to fix the issue. It does seem to be an Electron related issue as I replicated this with a clean installation.

Comment: I currently have the same problem, do you know what solution could help?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>After some digging through, I think I've found another answer.</sub>

After I got your code on my system, and followed all of the steps in your question, it worked correctly on my end.

Maybe you should check your versions of Electron (and Chromium), and update them if needed.

---

For you, delete the `node_modules` folder (and `package-lock.json`, if it helps), and then run the command below again.

```
$ npm install
```

<sub>*Note: Ignore the **$**. Also, make sure to run the command in your project directory!*</sub>

This will ensure you are running the latest versions of everything!

---

After some investigation on my side, I've concluded that it might be an issue with Chrome, and not Electron, as Electron simply runs Chromium inside the window, regardless of what it does.