# Electron starts unfocused (responds to double clicks only)

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm developing a test application using Electron 18.

I noticed that sometimes on mac the app starts without the focus.

If I click on the window nothing change, I noticed that performing a double click the html buttons are pressed but the window remain unfocused.

My code if very very easy:

Html:

```
<button>Test</button>
<hr>
```

Also the main.js is basic:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, screen, globalShortcut } = require('electron');

const createWindow = () => {
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600
})

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})
```

Nothing more..

I start the app with `elecrtron ./` and sometime, I get the windows unfocus as the following image (as you can see the app name is gray, unfocused):
[image]

It happen more ofter when I press ctrl+R to refresh the page

Comment: I wonder if this is a symptom of a corrupt Electron Chrome binary? See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71534851/unable-to-edit-input-element-after-an-alert-in-electron/71642174#71642174) to a  question with a similar non-responsive Chrome issue. If this works, let me know and I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it still happen after clearing node_modules and packagelock

Comment: What happens when you add `.then(() => { win.focus(); });` after your `win.load('index.html')` statement?

Comment: It may have something to do with garbage collection of the `win` object as well (maybe...). Make it global within your `main.js` file, convert your anonymous function `const createWindow = () => {...};` into a function declaration `function createWindow() {...};` and return `win` from it. Then on `app.whenReady()` update the next line to `win = createWindow();`. What happens then?

Comment: I have the same issue, node18, electron21. I tried removing the node_modules folder and all the lock files, no luck! Also, adding the win.focus(); after load did not change anything. For me, about 50% of the time the windows is unfocused. When its like that, double clicks act as single clicks and single clicks don't work. It can resolve itself by clicking away to another app, then back.  I have not tried this as a production app.

Comment: I confirmed my issue exists only on Mac, same code on Windows does not have this problem.