# Input focus not working in electron properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

So far I build a simple [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) application. My problem is the `input.focus()` is not working on displaying an alert box. I tried to solve the problem, and I came up with a solution: when I minimize and maximize the window, the `input.focus()` is working well. So when I try to show an alert box, the `input.focus()` isn't working, except minimize and maximizing. I try to open the code in Chrome, and all functionalities are working very well, so the problem is in the Electron renderer.

#### Before minimizing and maximizing the window

[image: Before maximizing the window]

#### After  minimizing and maximizing the window

[image]

#### My Electron renderer

```
const path = require("path");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 780,
    height: 600,
    minWidth: 780,
    minHeight: 600,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, "assets/favicon.ico"),
    webPreferences: {},
  });
  win.maximize();
  // win.removeMenu();
  win.loadFile("index.html");
};
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0)
      createWindow();
  });
});
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin")
    app.quit();
});
```

Comment: Confirming this works in a normal Chromium browser leads me to believe that there may be something wrong with Electron's bundled Chromium ([similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71534851/unable-to-edit-input-element-after-an-alert-in-electron)). Try deleting your node_modules folder and your package-lock.json file. Following this, re-install Electron by running npm install at the command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Input focus will lose if the app window not focused.

When you minimize and maximize the app window the input focus come back.

And When you send alert box the alert open in another window so the main app window blur and its input focus blur.